# how to fetch resouceID of azure resource

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

Can you please help to fetch resourceid in azure to call below restapi

$URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedAccess/azureResources/resources/****xxxxxxxxxxxx****/roleDefinitions`?`$filter=displayName eq 'Contributors'"

```
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers $Headers -Method Get
```

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `resource id` you need by requesting the `list`.

```
> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedAccess/azureResources/resources
```

[image]

please check:[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/governanceresource-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Comment: @DevReddy  Hi,i am very happy to help you,  you can accept it as an answer?